# How can I write my own Makefile (.mak file)?

Tags: c, makefile

I want to know how to write a `Makefile` (`.mak`-file).

I have 4 files:

1. `myfunctions.h`:

```
//myfunctions.h
#ifndef MYFUNCTIONS_H
#define MYFUNCTIONS_H

void show();

#endif
```

2. `myfunctions.c`:

```
//myfunctions.c
#include "myfunctions.h"

void show(){
printf("running!");
}
```

3. `mymain.c`:

```
//mymain.c
#include "myfunctions.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
show();
}
```

4. `mymake.mak`:

```
//mymake.mak
myprogramm: mymain.c myfunctions.c  
    gcc -o myprogramm mymain.c myfunctions.c -I.
```

I run the `mymake.mak` with `make mymakemak.mak` and I get this error:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `mymake.mak'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the file as the Makefile itself, not as the target. So you should be running

```
make -f mymake.mak
```

You can also rename `mymake.mak` to `Makefile` or `makefile` and re-run `make`.

What `make` is trying to do here is create a target called `mymake.mak`. Since `mymake.mak` already exists, `make` thinks its job is done and it exits.